# migrating geotiffs to iGIS tiles

Tags: qgis, kml, geotiff-tiff, tiles, igis

I recently shifted maps and waypoints from Delorme Xmap to QGIS on my Mac and wish to use iPhone/iGIS as the GPS (together with the Garmin GLO receiver). Everything is good in QGIS, but I need USGS topos as the base maps in iGIS, not the generic Google stuff used by iGIS. The app wants users to create tiled KML maps with MapTiler, which has a free version and pricier ones. I did create the tiles in MapTiler and they open just fine in Google Earth, but 1) the quality is very poor and 2) iGIS does not succeed in importing them. Seems like a very basic operation. Has anyone done this with any success?

[I should add that iGIS appears to be the only iPhone app out there that works with shapefiles and which reads / sends them to and from the Dropbox. This is important because QGIS only allows editing of waypoints in a shapefile layer (not CVS or GPX). If one creates the QGIS layer directly from the shapefile in the desktop Dropbox, the app communicates seamlessly with the desktop and waypoints are easily updated on both systems. If there is another iPhone app out there that does this, please let me know.]

---

The steps in the answer below worked well. Also, I was able to overcome the map quality issue in the 10KX10K file size limit in the free version of MapTiler by slicing my large geotiff file into 12 separate quadrants in QGIS and then processing each of those separately through MapTiler.

Answer (score 1):

The iGIS application requires TMS format.

Download http://www.maptiler.com/.

**Choose "Standard Mercator tiles" in the first screen of MapTiler,
then output to Folder and under "Advanced options" select the older "OSGEO TMS" tiling scheme.**

If you do this then the TMS tiles are generated together with "tilemapresource.xml" file in the folder and iGIS should be able to load these.

You need to create a ZIP from the directory and drag&drop it to iTunes while your tablet/phone is connected.

The process has been described with the older version of MapTiler at:http://www.geometryit.com/igis/?p=326